Unable to load Laravel APP_KEY/APP_NAME/etc.. via environment variable
I am attempting to setup the deployment of a Laravel app via Kubernetes, and have been trying to load the relevant env variables via k8s configmap and secrets, so I don't have to commit a .env file anywhere, however I am having a lot of trouble getting Laravel to recognise the values when they set as server env variables instaed of written into the .env file.
For the time being, forget the kubernetes element, as I have re-deployed without any of the config/secrets and am just trying to manually set the env variables and see if it works.
This is what is happening so far:
1.DEPLOY APPLICATION WITH NO K8S CONFIG/SECRETS AND NO .ENV FILE

Expected: 404 error due to missing .env file
Actual: 404 error due to missing .env file

1.1. COPY .ENV.EXAMPLE INTO .ENV WITH NO CHANGES

Expected: Error message about missing app_key
Actual: Error message about missing app_key

1.2 REMOVE EVERYTHING EXCEPT APP_* VARIABLES FROM .ENV & CLEAR CACHE

Expected: No change
Actual: No change

1.3. REMOVE APP_NAME FROM .ENV AND CHECK IT IN php artisan tinker > echo env('APP_NAME')

Expected: ""
Actual: ""

1.4. ADD ENV VARIABLE TO SERVER export APP_NAME="TEST" AND CHECK IT IN TINKER

Expected: "TEST"
Actual: "TEST"
(Confirmed: Laravel is picking up the env variable from the server)

1.5. CHECK APP_KEY IN TINKER

Expected: ""
Actual: ""

1.5. REMOVE EMPTY APP_KEY= FROM .ENV AND ADD ENV VARIABLE TO SERVER export APP_KEY="base64:ePh21Fg+NhX0y9Y7AHZnGn/Vkb8KSMnprJC0Ac/eVZs=" AND CHECK IT IN ARTISAN TINKER

Expected: "base64:ePh21Fg+NhX0y9Y7AHZnGn/Vkb8KSMnprJC0Ac/eVZs="
Actual: "base64:ePh21Fg+NhX0y9Y7AHZnGn/Vkb8KSMnprJC0Ac/eVZs="
(Confirmed the env variable is being picked up from the server)

1.6. CHECK SITE

Expected: Site works
Actual: Error message about missing app_key

1.7. CLEAR CACHE

Expected: Site works
Actual: Error message about missing app_key
Error trace: [2024-05-20 15:09:55] local.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\Encryption\MissingAppKeyException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at /var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php:101)

1.8. MANUALLY PUT AN APP_KEY INTO THE .ENV FILE (base64:XiH8Gd/5kXZfuqht5aptAjlkNshf4QzwvjGQ8GhbTWg=) [Note: This is different from the one we tried before]

Expected: Site works
Actual: Site works

1.9. CHECK TINKER FOR APP_KEY VALUE

Expected: "base64:XiH8Gd/5kXZfuqht5aptAjlkNshf4QzwvjGQ8GhbTWg=" - The value from .env file
Actual: "base64:ePh21Fg+NhX0y9Y7AHZnGn/Vkb8KSMnprJC0Ac/eVZs=" - The value we set with export

So, the problem seems to be that even though the function env('APP_KEY') returns the value from the server environment when checked in tinker, the site won't work unless you put something into the .env file. And it seems to return the server env variable from artisan tinker, but presumably returns the one from .env file when loaded through the browser, hence why it thinks its missing, even when the env variable on the server is set.
This means I can't load the value via an environment variable, but instead have to specifically write it into the .env file.
It's not a specific APP_KEY issue, as I've just noticed the same happens with APP_NAME. If I set it in .env file, it finds it correctly and sets it as the browser tab title. However, if I set it via env variable on the server instead, it defaults to "Laravel" despite tinker picking up the value "TEST".
Am I doing anything obviously wrong here? Am I totally misunderstanding how Laravel loads environment variables? I've looked at several guides on doing this with kubernetes secrets/configmaps, and they all load them into environment variables like this, rather than writing the .env file.
I've cleared the config and app caches multiple times throughout all this as well.
Larvel Framework 8.83.27
PHP 8.1.28
Thanks.

.env will not override any existing environment variables (which explains 1.9). The issue I think is that the app is served in such a way that it does not read the same exported Env variables that running tinker would read (maybe the webserver runs as a different user with a different set of variables?)

Hmm. Interesting theory. When I apply the env variables via kubernetes, and login to the container as root and run env i can see them, but when i switch to www-data I can't. So that seems plausible. However, then when I'm still logged in as www-data if I manually create them with export, it still doesn't pick them up, unless actually written into the .env file. It looks like it just doesn't like them being environment variables at all. Maybe I will have to have a script which writes a .env on deployment or something. Very odd.

Might be worth restarting the php-fpm service and/or the webserver service after you export them as www-data in case they get cached
